# Keeping my nav when you scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to design a website for my company, but I can't figure one thing.

I want navbar fixed while people scroll down the page

like this one
http://www.quintessentially.com   (as you can see, the navigation bar gets fixed when you scroll down the page )

I'm using  jQuery 1.8.3.min.js 
and this code

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $('.nav').addClass('absolute');
     }
     else {
         $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
     }
});
```

and the css is like this

```
header .nav{
top: 55px;
padding: 0;
min-height: 0;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
line-height: 3px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
}

.fixed{
position: fixed;
top: 0;  }
```

But I don't why it isn't working. 
Does someone know how to fix it?

Thanks !! :D

ps: sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Please also add some pertinent HTML so we can test.

Comment: I don't see a CSS class for "absolute", which is the class you are adding when the user has scrolled past 50 px from the top.  Also, you are only removing the 'fixed' class when the user scrolls to the top, but you never add it back in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the logic.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $('.nav').
          .removeClass('absolute')
          .addClass('fixed');
     }
     else {
         $('.nav')
          .removeClass('fixed')
          .addclass('absolute');
     }
});
```

Added a removeClass as well to prevent any class priority issues.

Comment: Keep in mind that running this eval on every scroll event would be a performance killer. You could use conditional logic to remedy this, then use unbind, maybe.